# Elasticsearch JEST date serialization java

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, serialization, elasticsearch-jest

I am using ES Jest. I can make a search and get the response. But when I do the serialization with the `Date` property, I got a `null` response after serialization.

The following is my class for ES document index and search result:

```
public class IndexDocument {
  public long id;
  @JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
  public Date Date1;
  @JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
  public Date Date2;
}
```

I have the following code for Date serialization:

```
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Response from ES:

```
"hits" : [{
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "mytype",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.3294203,
        "_source" : {
            "Date1" : "2016-11-24T14:39:08.000Z",
            "id" : 1,
            "Date2" : "1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
    }
]
```

My serialization code:

```
JestResult result = client.execute(search);   // i can see the response here 
response =  result.getSourceAsObjectList(IndexDocument.class);
```

After serialization, I get `response = null`

If I remove the date property from `indexDocument`, I can see the serialized response. However, with the date property, it is not working. What went wrong?

Comment: I'm trying the example above and it works fine. Can you post your mapping? Mine is auto-generated when indexing the example above, but you might have something different. I'm using jackson 2.4.6

Answer (score 2):

JEST uses gson to parse dates, so your jackson annotation is not used when search result is parsed by jest.
You might find this solution helpful:
https://jtruty.github.io/programming/2015/04/03/elasticsearch-http-queries-with-jest.html